# Extract two hex variables from a string

Tags: bash, sed, makefile

I'm having a input like that

```
field = <0xaaa 0xbbb>;
```

and would like to extract the two hex values so they can be used in a Makefile.

How would I go about that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove everything surrounding the two values with:

```
sed 's/.*<\(.*\)>.*/\1/'
```

Test:

```
% echo 'field = <0xaaa 0xbbb>;' | sed 's/.*<\(.*\)>.*/\1/'
0xaaa 0xbbb
```

If you need to dereference the values to variables:

```
declare -a values=($(sed 's/.*<\(.*\)>.*/\1/' input_file))

echo "${values[0]}" # 0xaaa
echo "${values[1]}" # 0xbbb
# ... If there are more lines in input_file then the array will be bigger ...
# ${values[2]} will contain next lValue
# ${values[3]} will contain next rValue
# ... and so on ...
```

Comment: This will grab anything in `<>`'s, if you need something more specific to hex you can try something like: `grep -o '\b0x[[:xdigit:]]\{3\}\b'`

Comment: @A.Danischewski Thats true, but it might not be necessary for OP needs. And didn't know about `xdigit` thats a nice one.